# How to write metered poetry, when you can only read 'phonetically'?

Tags: poetry

I have dyslexia, and when I pronounce words in my head the syllable count and stress doesn't reflect the way the words are pronounced in everyday speech. I think you might describe it as phonetic pronounciation?

For instance, the [IPA pronunciation](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/strength#Pronunciation) for 'Strength':

> /stɹɛŋkθ/, [st̠͡ɹ̠ɛŋkθ], [st̠͡ɹ̠ɛn̪θ]

However I found when I was trying to work out the syllables for this word, I would say (in my head) the word how I learnt to spell it:

> stʌ•ɹ̠ɛn•gʌ•θʌ

Which is ~4 syllables, but when I speak the words out loud as part of a line of poetry (with the standard pronunciation) I can't for the life of me hear where the stress falls.

As an example, I tried to write this limerick for a puzzle:

> These strings of digits are unique
> My first in time and space so to speak
> And so, you'll find, is my second
> with three 'n' five names are reckoned,
> And fourth's the random assignment technique

However I got [feedback](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7241/9316) that it didn't scan, I figured out that my struggles were with the in-head/out-loud pronunciation I described above.

This is the 'fixed' version:

> These many strings of digits unique
> First made from space and time so to speak
> The same for my second
> Three 'n' five: names reckoned,
> And my fourth has a random technique

But now this version doesn't quite sound right to me either.

Is there a way for me to check the meter, syllables and stress for writing poetry without relying on my (faulty) pronounciation?

Comment: Move to a structure with *loose meter* to match your vocabulary and theme. The 'awkwardness' is the poetic styles clash: *Limerick* (folk-entertainment, bawdy punchlines, said aloud in a sing-song rhythm and exact syllables) verses *Romantic Poetry* (literary metaphors about pastoral life, with a lilting anti-rhythm in counterpoint to actual words, merging and replacing syllables with apostrophes to emphasize anti-meter in the text) –– It's like Cardi B singing opera or Maria Callas singing about her WAP – it won't 'sound right' because these poem styles are incongruent in rhythm and tone.

Comment: If your goal is to write 'metered poetry' as in your question, simplify your vocabulary and sentence structure for sharper impact. The more meter, the more 'on the nose' the subject matter should be to match. Limericks, like pop music, use familiar meter as a hook to focus the mind and telegraph the 'punch' ending…. Abstraction and metaphor invite playful deconstruction of meter and language. Poetry that harkens back to ye olde pastoral times will be freer with meter and stylized language to reflect how the mind wanders in the organic quaintness of nature.

Comment: How is your pronunciation when you're not reading? (Namely when performing a poem you've memorized.)

Comment: @Laurel pronounciation when reading out loud is fine, but then I'm not conscious of the meter/rhythm etc. I haven't ever memorised poetry.

Comment: If you say a single word out loud, can you tell the stress pattern? For example, in your second version, one of the reasons it doesn't scan properly is that "many" in general has the stress on the first syllable (MAN-ee), but in your poem (based on the feedback you linked) you want it to stress the second syllable (ma-NEE). If you just say the word "many" out loud can you tell the difference?

Comment: As a good test--can you tell the different between hearing/speaking the words "desert" (dry sandy place) and "dessert" (delicious after-meal treat)? The only difference there is which syllable is stressed. How about perfect the adjective (that cake is perfect) vs the verb (we have to perfect that cake recipe)?

Comment: @Kitkat I don't hear *any* clear stress.... maybe a slight favouring of 'meh-nee', but only because when I *try* to stress it as 'MAN-ee' it sounds everso slightly wrong. Until now if you'd had asked I'd say the word is completely unstressed

Comment: @Kitkat I say something that sounds to me like 'DUZ-sert' for the food, and 'DEH-sert' for the dry sandy place. and I'm not sure about the noun/verb difference in 'perfect', I can tell the stress is different, but I'm either not inclined towards one or the other, I'm not hearing it or I'm just enunciating the R more clearly in one than the other.

Comment: Hmm. So when you say the two words (desert/dessert) out loud, the only difference between them is how you pronounce the first syllable? Try saying them out loud and really stress the first syllable and see if one of them sounds weird/off. Also, here's a list of words that change meaning when their stress is different--see if you can distinguish between them. https://www.engvid.com/english-resource/35-words-stress-changes-meaning/

Comment: Otherwise, a general rule of thumb is that conjunctions/prepositions/etc--unimportant words--are usually unstressed in poetry. In this poem you have stress on "from" and "for", where we'd expect the stress to be on the nouns/verbs surrounding. Otherwise "many", "second", and "reckoned" all have the stress on the wrong syllable (based on your goal scanning from your link). The majority of two syllable words have their stress on the first syllable, so you're probably best assuming that but also checking a dictionary? (since you are correct that unique and technique have their second stressed)

Comment: Just noticed this related question: [Scansion tool for checking my meter](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43000/5232)

Answer (score 2):

Going from the basis in comments that you can't hear the differences in stress when reading your poem out loud, here's what you could do:

1. Make a stress map of how you want your poem to be. For example, in the first line of a limerick you could do:

- da da DA, da da DA, da da DA (this is how the last line of your second sample scans)
- da Da, da da DA, da da DA da ("There once was a man from Nantucket")

etc. Your lines 1, 2, and 5 just all should be the same (possibly dropping the first syllable in some but let's not get into that :D), and then same with 3 and 4.

2. Write your lines based on your stress map, with one poem syllable per stress syllable.

- Look up multi-syllable words in the dictionary and make sure they're placed appropriately
- "Small words" -- conjunctions, prepositions, sometimes pronouns and is/was/etc, should generally be unstressed. If you have an "important word" (a noun, verb, adjective, etc) next to a "small word", make the important word the stressed one.

3. Give your poem to a friend to make sure it scans!

---

If we dive into your example:

> These many strings of digits unique
>
> First made from space and time so to speak
>
> The same for my second
>
> Three 'n' five: names reckoned,
>
> And my fourth has a random technique

Taking line by line:

> These many strings of digits unique

You want it to scan like this:

> These man-NY strings of DIG-its u-NIQUE

First problem here is that it's the "man" in "many" that is meant to be stressed, rather than the "ny". So, we can't scan it like that.

So, our brains decide to scan it with "man" stressed, like this:

> These MAN-y strings OF digits U-nique

Which also doesn't work because it puts the emphasis on the wrong syllable of "unique". Also, emphasizing "of" when "strings" and "dig" are right there is odd.

Scanning our second line in the same two ways, we either end up emphasizing "from" (which is weird because "made" and "space" are both more important words) or else we emphasize both "and" and "to", which also don't make sense to focus on.

For lines three and four, think about the first three syllables of each:

> The same for

> Three 'n five

The important words here are "same", "three", and "five". The problem is they're on different syllables on each line. So if we scan the first like this:

> The SAME for my SEC-ond

That's fine. But that would make our next line:

> Three N five names RECK-oned

Which puts the stress on "N"--the least important part of the line.

Alternatively, if you do:

> The same FOR my sec-OND
>
> Three 'n FIVE so reck-ONED

You're both emphasizing "for", and you're putting the stress on the wrong syllable of "second" and "reckoned".

The last line scans correctly.

Comment: This has literally made my day, I'll have to digest it later, but this is amazing